# Unable to utilized the value of an index loop inside a test in Playwright

Tags: playwright, playwright-typescript

I have a scenario where I would like to have my test cases inside a loop and handle some pre and post test events by using the `beforeEach` and `afterEach` while utilizing the index loop value, but encountered a different outcome.

**Sample Code**

```
let index: number;
test.describe('Inside a loop test', async () => {
    test.beforeEach(async() => {
        console.log('Before each #' + index);
    });
    for (index = 0; index <= 5; index++) {
        test('Test #' + index, async({}, testInfo) =>{
            console.log('Test name: ' + testInfo.title);
            console.log('Test #' + index);
        });
    }
    test.afterEach(async() => {
        console.log('After each #' + index);
    });
});
```

On the sample code above, I'm trying to use the `index` value inside my test, but is always returning only the last possible value, which is 6. The `index` value in the `test` title is correct though.

**Output**

```
Running 6 tests using 1 worker

Before each #6
Test name: Test #0
Test #6
After each #6

Before each #6
Test name: Test #1
Test #6
After each #6

Before each #6
Test name: Test #2
Test #6
After each #6

Before each #6
Test name: Test #3
Test #6
After each #6

Before each #6
Test name: Test #4
Test #6
After each #6

Before each #6
Test name: Test #5
Test #6
After each #6
  6 passed (658ms)
```

I declared `index` in the outer level thinking that it will also help the `beforeEach` and `afterEach`, but, unfortunately, only the last value of the `index` is being considered.

Am I missing something on the [Parameterize tests](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-parameterize) of Playwright?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the loop outside the entire describe block and it will run as expected:

```js
for (let index = 0; index <= 5; index++) {
  test.describe("Inside a loop test", async () => {
    test.beforeEach(async () => {
      console.log("Before each #" + index);
    });
    test("Test #" + index, async ({}, testInfo) => {
      console.log("Test name: " + testInfo.title);
      console.log("Test #" + index);
    });
    test.afterEach(async () => {
      console.log("After each #" + index);
    });
  });
}
```

Output:

```
Before each #0
Test name: Test #0
Test #0
After each #0

Before each #1
Test name: Test #1
Test #1
After each #1

Before each #2
Test name: Test #2
Test #2
After each #2

Before each #3
Test name: Test #3
Test #3
After each #3

Before each #4
Test name: Test #4
Test #4
After each #4

Before each #5
Test name: Test #5
Test #5
After each #5
```

The reason for this is in JS the foor loop does not wait for the async function to finish. In other words: by the time the async function starts executing, the for loop has already completed all its iterations, and the index value has reached its final value.

Answer (score 0):

I would invoke it using closure functions

```
test.describe('Inside a loop test', async ({ page }) => {
    for (let index = 0; index <= 5; index++) {
        (function (currentIndex) {
            test.beforeEach(async () => {
                console.log('Before each #' + currentIndex);
            });

            test(`Test #${currentIndex}`, async () => {
                console.log('Test #' + currentIndex);
                // Example test action
                await page.goto('https://example.com');
                // Add your Playwright test actions here
            });

            test.afterEach(async () => {
                console.log('After each #' + currentIndex);
            });
        })(index);
    }
});
```